# Taxonomy Child Term, Counter is staying on 0

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions

I'm stuck on the counter for the child term.

See Image:

[image]

**What did i try?**

Make use of:

- wp_defer_term_counting(true);
- wp_update_term_count();

Both of this functions didn't work inside my code.

Making use of wp_insert_term();

Does someone has a solution to update the child term count when saving your post?

Comment: If you click on the count of `0`, how many posts are actually in that child category?

Comment: 0 posts are attached

Comment: You won't see that count go up until posts are attached.